# changing Div height parameters does nothing to the size

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out why the `height` of this container(`summaryBox`) is not changing. I have tried setting the `min-height`, `max-height` and changing some other things but nothing is working. I wanted the `height` of the container to be 20% of the screen, but its not working. Everything else works fine and I am scratching my head.

CSS:

```
.summaryBox {
        border: 1px solid green ;
        width: 80%;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        min-height: 20%;
}

.summaryBox .img1 {
        width: 21%;
        float: left;
        color: white;
        padding: 0px .5% 0px .5%;
}

.summaryBox .img2 {
        width: 21%;
        float: left;
        color: white;
        padding: 0px .5% 0px .5%;
}

.summaryBox .sum1 {
        width: 21%;
        float: left;
        color: white;
        padding: 0px .5% 0px .5%;
}

.summaryBox .sum2 {
        width: 21%;
        float: left;
        color: white;
        padding: 0px .5% 0px .5%;
}

.summaryBox .arrowPanelLeft {
        float: left;
        width: 6%;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
}

.summaryBox .arrowPanelRight {
        float: right;
        width: 6%;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="summaryBox">
    <div class="arrowPanelLeft">
            <p><</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img1">
        <p>dasfafgafdgdafgdfsgdsfgdfsgdsfg</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sum1">
        <p>dasfafgafdgdafgdfsgdsfgdfsgdsfg</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img2">
        <p>dasfafgafdgdafgdfsgdsfgdfsgdsfg</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sum2">
        <p>dasfafgafdgdafgdfsgdsfgdfsgdsfg</p>
    </div>
    <div class="arrowPanelRight">
            <p>></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the height of the html and body elements, as well. This is something 'CSS resets' (such as Eric Meyer's) will usually do for you. Append this code to your css file:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have set `.summeryBox` height to a percentage.. of what? 
You need to add this to your css:

```
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }
```

Then the `.summeryBox` will be set relative to the body tag.

Alternatively you can set the outer container (`.summeryBox`) dimensions in pixels.

Comment: That worked thank-you, but how come you do not need to set the width in the body as well?

Comment: You should do that, otherwise the width of your elements will wrap to content. See the edit.

Comment: NP. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem :)